# Explicitly mark a property on a directive scope dirty

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I recently began using AngularJS in a web app that up to this point has been mostly jQuery based. One of the UI components in this app uses jQuery UI's draggable, which uses CSS's `left` property to position objects while being dragged. The problem I am having is that I bind `left` to a percentage value held in a scope property.

```
<div class="seeker" data-ng-style="{ left: position + '%' }">
    <div class="handle"></div>
</div>
```

I figured it would be simple enough to listen for the drag `stop` event and do the conversion myself. This works fine in most cases, but despite having set the `containment` field to the parent element (`.timeline-control`) of the draggable element, sometimes the draggable element ends up slightly outside its parent. The follow code compensates for those situations.

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.find(".seeker").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: elem.find(".timeline-control"),
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var $t = $(event.target);
            var position = $t.position().left / $t.parent().outerWidth() * 100;
            position = Math.min(position, 100);
            position = Math.max(position, 0);
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.position = position;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The problem with this code is that if the draggable element is dragged outside the parent's far right, the `scope.position` binding is only updated the first time it is set to 100. The binding does not occur on successive drags. I realize this is because scope.position value has not actually changed and is not considered dirty by the framework, but the elements style has changes, so I would like for the binding to take place anyway.

### **Edit**

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IzY04gQ9oCa5dGVsnHzQ) is a plunker demonstrating the behavior. Drag the red bar to the far right of the container and release it. At this point it works as expected. Drag it to the right and release again and you will see that the red bar breaks containment (jqueryui draggable bug?). Repeat to see the behavior.

Research into the problem with jQuery draggable not keeping containment led me to [this](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7016) issue.

I can think of a number of hackish ways to make this work, but I was hoping there was a clean solution out there, like explicitly marking the property dirty. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about setting the form controller $isDirty flag take a look here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController at $setDirty()

Comment: I did find that page, but unfortunately I don't think it applies since I am not using a form or the form controller.

Comment: Assumption incorrect, moving on... So is the reason you want to set it as `dirty` so that you can update the position in ng-style?

Comment: That is correct. jQueryUI draggable sets the CSS left property to a pixel value, but I want it set as a percentage. I realize I could just modify the CSS property directly with jQuery, but I was hoping to do it the Angular way.

Comment: Can you post the full code of your directive or make a fiddle?

Comment: Updated question with a link to a plunker demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Your plnkr seems to be working, or is it not because you want it to have it update as you are dragging?

Comment: See my previous edit. Everything behaves as desired until the `.seeker` breaks containment on the far right of the container.

Answer (score 1):

You sir have given me a headache. I know you're looking for a non-hackish solution, but these are the two options I have come up with. Even though they are hackish I felt like sharing them in case they appeal to you.

1) apply a *minor* scope change then immediately set it back

```
scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.position = position - .00000001;
});
scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.position = position;
});
```

2) instead of binding your scope.position explicitly set the left style via jQuery:

```
elem.css('left', position + '%');
```

Comment: I up-voted your question in hopes that it will gain some attention.

Comment: And an up-vote for you, for the headache I've caused you. 

In the end I decided to [rework](http://plnkr.co/edit/Si1Qv56nJjhlkGpAzLUj) my DOM structure to avoid the jQueryUI draggable containment issues, and not rely on binding position to the `left` property.